# How to print c++ code on new terminal line

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I just have this simple Hello world program that I would like to run in terminal.

```
#include <iostream> 
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

And when I run the output file in the terminal. It prints like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7QpD.png)

Is there anyway to have the output come out on a new line instead. So it's more like:

*Hello World!

*new terminal line

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::cout << "Hello World!\n";`

Comment: If you want a new line ... just print a new line? Any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will cover this, probably on the first few pages. Or put "C++ print newline" or similar into your favorite search engine. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << "Hello World!\n"
```

or

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl
```

Comment: you should only use `std::endl` if you really need to flush the stream, its usually unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

`std::cout << "Hello World!\n";`

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

```
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
```

or

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

Comment: you should only use `std::endl` if you really need to flush the stream, its usually unnecessary